# Setting HTML id attribute on text_area with formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I would like to assign a specific `id` attribute to my `text_area` field and could not make it work with Formtastic.

Actual state of my code: (doesn't work)

```erb
<%= f.text_area :message, :id => 'element_id' -%>
```

I tried:

```erb
<%= f.text_area :message, :input_html => {:id => 'element_id'} -%>
```

Which doesn't work as it created a `input_html` attibute inside the `text_area` HTML element.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Anything wrong with HTML?

```
<textarea id="element_id"></textarea>
```

**Update**

By using f.text_area you're circumventing the label generation as you're directly generating a field. This should generate your textarea correctly (sans label)

```
<%= f.text_area "message", :value => '', :id => 'element_id' %>
```

If you want label generation you should be doing

```
<%= f.input :message, :as => :text %>
```

However I don't think you can overwrite the ID when using the generator... The text type defaults if your database type is `:text`

Comment: The idea is to go through the helper, as it sets everything for you, the label, the error message, etc. I don't want to do that by hand.

Comment: You're manually making a text_area not using formtastic to generate one so you won't get a label.